# Jquery get next sibling

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am facing some issues while getting elements of the sibling using jquery. I will try to explain.

The following is the HTML that i am currently working on ..

```
<p class="paraclass1" id="amazing1">
  <span class ="pascal1">
    <div class='pascal'>
        <INPUT id= "chk1" value="on" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  </span>
</p>
<p>
  <label class='lblclass'>this is a label </>
</p>
```

what i would like to do is to navigate and find all the children that are present in the second p tag  (right now only a label is present) .  The following is the Jquery code that i am working on ..

```
$('#chk1').click(function(){
  alert($(this).parents('p#amazing1').next().children().length)

 // alert($('#chk1').parent().parent().attr('class'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gj1118/vWQxD/5/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**
I am now trying to get the text of the label that is inside the second p tag element and its not working.... Is there something that I am missing .. ? I havent changed the fiddle yet , but since it was just a sample and since the tags were not being used, i let it remain like it for the sake of simplicity

Comment: The fiddle worked when I changed the div to a span: http://jsfiddle.net/vWQxD/6/ - presumably because you're not supposed to include divs in spans. Note also that `.closest()` is a better choice than `.parents()` for what you're doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your jQuery should work fine. The problem in this case is your markup. The [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-p-element) can only contain "[phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#phrasing-content-1)". The `div` element is not classed as phrasing content, so the browser will do its best to handle your markup by moving things around.

Chrome simply moves the `p` element to become the previous sibling of the `div`.

To fix the issue, you will need to change your markup. Your best bet may be to change the `p` element into another `div`. See an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWQxD/8/).

---

*Side note*. You may want to consider changing the `.parents()` call to a `.closest()` call. The `.parents()` method can return multiple elements if they match the selector. In this case that's not possible, but in the interest of maintainability, it could be a good change:

```
$(this).closest('#amazing1').next().children().length
```

Comment: I think it simply closes the p tag once it sees a div tag.

Comment: @SalmanA - Yes, that's exactly what it does, said in a nicer way than I put it!